# Why does my mobile browser show a different picture than an iPad?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

So I'm making a responsive website and for that there is one part of it which contains the following code:

```
/* Firefox */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
/* WebKit */
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
/* Opera */
width: -o-calc(100% - 50px);
/* Standard */
width: calc(100% - 50px);
```

And it works great on tablets and desktops, but not on phones. Is there some kind of a fallback that I could use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Almost always `box-sizing: border-box` can replace a `calc` rule such as `calc(100% - 50px)` used for layout.

For example:

If I have the following markup:

```
<div class="sideBar">sideBar</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Instead of doing this: (Assuming that the sidebar is 50px wide)

```
.content {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Do this:

```
.content {
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```